# Given two non-zero vectors a and b such that |a + b| = |a - b|, find the value of a • b

Tags: vectors

Given two non-zero vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ such that |$\vec{a}$ + $\vec{b}$| = |$\vec{a}$ - $\vec{b}$|, 
find the value of $\vec{a}$ • $\vec{b}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|\vec{a} + \vec{b}|^{2} = |\vec{a} - \vec{b}|^{2}$
$\vec{a}+\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}+ \vec{b}=\vec{a}-\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}+ \vec{b}
\\\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}=0
$

Comment: that's a simple and effective answer.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $$||a+b||=||a-b|| \implies ||a+b||^2=||a-b||^2$$ 
which is just 
$$(a+b)\cdot(a+b)=(a-b)\cdot(a-b)$$
Expand that equation and see how things cancel.

Answer (score 1):

It is equivalent to

$$ |a+b|^2 = |a-b|^2 $$

and s o

$$ (a+b) \cdot (a+b) = (a-b) \cdot (a-b) $$

and so

$$ a^2 + 2 a \cdot b + b^2 = a^2 - 2 a \cdot b + b^2 $$

can you finish it ?

Comment: Both your $\;\cdot\;$ and your * seem to be same: inner product. Why different notation? The last line also may confuse...or maybe you meant like Newton's binomial? Because if the linear space is unitary then it is false...